# How to write data from a file into a list filled with class instances?

Tags: python, list, class

I'm rather new to python. I thought about creating a simple studentslist as a "beginning" programm. My idea was to have a .txt file with information about several students and read the data into a list full of Student classes. And after that let the "user" do some stuff with the data.

I've tried to read the data and split it so i can add a new Student() instance into the list with the splitted information.

However, that didn't work that well.

```
class Student:
     def __init__(self, name, number, age):
          self.name = name
          self.number = number
          self.age = age

     def StartUp():
          with open("students.txt", "r") as file:
              contents = file.readlines()

          studentslist = []

          for line in contents:
              line = line.rstrip()
              x = line.split(" ")
              studentslist.append(Student(x[0], x[1], x[2]))
         return studentslist



   #  the data in the .txt file look like this:
   #  Michael 3 17
   #  Jake 16 18
   #  and so on
```

After running the application and printig studentslist it prints the locations of each Students in the memory.

How can i make it so i get the actual values? Or maybe write it more simplyfied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as @Mayank mentions, you need to override the `__repr__` and `__str__` methods in order to manage to print an object the way you want. Then you will be able to get all students from the file and print them or store them in list:

```
class Student:
  def __init__(self, name, number, age):
    self.name = name
    self.number = number
    self.age = age

  def __repr__(self):
    return " ".join(list(map(str,[self.name,self.number,self.age])))

def loadStudents():
  with open('students.txt','r') as inFile:
    lines = [line.split() for line in inFile]
    students = [Student(elem[0], int(elem[1]), int(elem[2])) for elem in lines]
    return students

loadStudents()
```

Comment: I see. I didn't think python would handle class instances this way. Though i'm wondering why theres no need of the rstrip() function to remove the trailing newlines from each but the last element of lines. Maybe the split() function automatically removes the "\n"?

Comment: `split()` removes any whitespace character, newlines included, so it will work without the use of `rstrip()`.

Answer (score 0):

You must be printing the list containing your `Student` objects directly. By default, Python prints the memory locations of objects, since it doesn't know how to print a string representation of it. You can define this for your class by either defining `__repr__` or `__str__` special methods.

You can define a `__str__()` method in your `Student` class like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "name: {}, number: {}, age: {}".format(self.name, self.number, self.age)
```

Have a look at this article if you want to learn more about Python's special methods:
http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/special-method-names.html